# Google Calendar API and UI Widget - Java

Tags: java, calendar, google-calendar-api

My company wants to add a calendar to our website. The requirements are:

- A calendar widget on a web page shows company events
- User can search locally (show events near city / zip code)
- User cannot add events

I see in the API documentation a lot of information about using calendar V3 as a back end data service, but nothing about a front end and integration to web pages.

Is it possible? Is there a UI widget that can talk to calendar V3 API?

If so where is the documentation about instantiating a calendar widget on a web page, and connecting it to the V3 API?